# Javascript : Adding extra input form when one checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

How to add one extra input form when one checkbox is clicked ?

Comment: Please put some effort into an attempt. If it doesn't work and you can't find out why, we can help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify your checkbox that will be checked, and the container which will contain the new input field (I am assuming that you want a textbox in my example for simplicity... change it to whatever you'd like). This is an extremely basic example that you will have to modify based on your needs, but you get the idea.

Using this HTML:

```
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" />
<div id="formContainer">
</div>​
```

You can apply this JavaScript:

```
function CreateTextbox() {
    var textBox = document.createElement("input");
    textBox.setAttribute("type", "textbox");
    textBox.setAttribute("id", textboxId);
    textboxId++;
    return textBox;
}

var textboxId = 0;

document.getElementById("chk").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("formContainer").appendChild(CreateTextbox(textboxId));
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hcmG2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you need http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript/ ? You just need to call the `add()` function when checkbox clicked.